# how to get audio on clickeing the image using javascript and pause when playing two or more images one must pasued while other is playing

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <img  class="cl"src="photo/198.jpg"/></br>
    <audio class="cs" controls>
       <source src="audio/198 banu nagamothu.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

I dont want controls to audio first but when i clicked the image audio should played using javascript and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AudioElement.paused` property!

```js
$('.cl').click(function() {
  var DOMElem = $('.cs').get(0);
  DOMElem.paused ? DOMElem.play() : DOMElem.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
</br>
<audio class="cs">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: @banuprakash — What is not working ? What is the error ?

Comment: @banuprakash — Check the update....

Comment: @banuprakash — Just remove `controls` attribute...

Comment: @banuprakash you have not included jQuery library!

Comment: if we place more than 5 images? and each has a its audio file when it is clicked  played but when clicking on the other image i want to stop first one and to play another one

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$('.cl').click(function() {
  if ($('.cs').paused == false) {
      $('.cs').pause();
      alert('pause');
  } else {
      $('.cs').play();
      alert('play');
  }
});
```

Comment: `paused` is not a property of `jQuery` object...